# How to use facebook/google login button to store user information with react redux

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, react-redux

I want to use facebook/goolge login button to automatically store user's information to the server. Right now, it seems that the information has been passed to the API part (I mean at least the program tried...). In most of the cases there is no error, but the login page is blank, but I still received this kind of error message.

```
 bundle.js:72621 Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
at FacebookButton.componentDidMount (bundle.js:72621)
at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (bundle.js:6532)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (bundle.js:16290)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (bundle.js:6893)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (bundle.js:6840)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (bundle.js:2740)
at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (bundle.js:6827)
at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:10864)
at Object.batchedUpdates (bundle.js:6332)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (bundle.js:2934)
```

Here is the code for my action part:

```
import { FACEBOOKLOGIN } from "../constants/index";
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
//FACEBOOKLOGIN
export function facebookLogin(props){
  const request = axios.post(`${API_URL}/users`,{
    user: {
      email:props.email,
      password:props.password,
      password_confirmation:props.password
    }
  });
  return{
    type: FACEBOOKLOGIN,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

and here is my facebook login function

```
       import React, { Component, PropTypes }from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { facebookLogin } from '../../actions/index';
import { FACEBOOKLOGIN } from '../../constants/index';


var password = {password: "zsy2053@gmail.com"};
function validate(values) {
  const errors = {}

  if (!values.password) {
    values.password = password;
  }

  return errors
}
class FacebookButton extends React.Component {

  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.FB = props.fb;

      this.state = {
         message: ""
      };
      this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
   }

   onClick(props){
     this.props.facebookLogin(props)
     .then(() => {
       this.context.router.push('/');
     });
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout',
         this.onLogout.bind(this));
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange',
         this.onStatusChange.bind(this));
   }

   onStatusChange(response) {
      console.log( response );
      var self = this;

      if( response.status === "connected" ) {
         FB.api('/me', { locale: 'tr_TR', fields: 'name, email,birthday, hometown,education,gender,website,work' },
         function(response) {
           console.log(response.email);
           console.log(response.name);
           console.log(response.gender);
           console.log(response.birthday);
           console.log(response.hometown);
           console.log(response.education);
           console.log(response.website);
           console.log(response.work);
           var message;
            self.setState({
               message: response.email
            });
         })
      }
   }

   onLogout(response) {
      this.setState({
         message: ""
      });
   }

   render() {
     const { fields: { email, password }, handleClick, submitting } = this.props
      return (
         <div>
         <div className=
         "fb-login-button"
         data-max-rows="1"
         data-size="medium"
         data-show-faces="true"
         data-auto-logout-link="true"
         onclick={this.onClick}></div>
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
         </div>
      );
   }
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'FacebookButton',
  fields: ['email','password'],
  validate
},null,{facebookLogin})(FacebookButton)
```

and here is my login form where I render my facebook button

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import googleLogin from './google_login.js';
import FacebookButton from './facebook_login.js';



function validate(values) {
  const errors = {}

  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required'
  } else if (!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Please enter a valid email address'
  }

  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required'
  }

  return errors
}



class LoginForm extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };



  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }

  signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }

  onSubmit(props){
    this.props.loginUser(props)
    .then(() => {
      this.context.router.push('/');
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { fields: { email, password }, handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.loginUser)}>
          <div className={`form-group ${email.touched && email.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <div>
            {/* {email.touched && email.error && <div className={s.textError}>{email.error}</div>} */}
              <input type="email" className="form-control" {...email}/>
              <div className="email-help-login">
                {email.touched ? email.error : ''}
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div className={`form-group ${password.touched && password.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
            <label>Password</label>
            <div>
            {/* {password.touched && password.error && <div className={s.textError}>{password.error}</div>} */}
              <input type="password" className="form-control" {...password}/>
              <div className="password-help-login">
                {password.touched ? password.error : ''}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
               Login
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
          </div>


        </form>
        <FacebookButton fb={FB} />



        <googleLogin/>
        <a href="#" onclick="this.signOut();">Sign out</a>


      </div>

    )
  }
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  fields: ['email','password'],
  validate
},null,{loginUser})(LoginForm)
```

Here is my login page:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/index';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { FACEBOOKLOGIN } from '../../constants/index';
import googleLogin from './google_login.js';
import FacebookButton from './facebook_login.js';



function validate(values) {
  const errors = {}

  if (!values.email) {
    errors.email = 'Required'
  } else if (!/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(values.email)) {
    errors.email = 'Please enter a valid email address'
  }

  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = 'Required'
  }

  return errors
}



class LoginForm extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
  };



  onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
  }

  signOut() {
      var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        console.log('User signed out.');
      });
    }

  onSubmit(props){
    this.props.loginUser(props)
    .then(() => {
      this.context.router.push('/');
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { fields: { email, password }, handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.loginUser)}>
          <div className={`form-group ${email.touched && email.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
            <label>E-mail</label>
            <div>
            {/* {email.touched && email.error && <div className={s.textError}>{email.error}</div>} */}
              <input type="email" className="form-control" {...email}/>
              <div className="email-help-login">
                {email.touched ? email.error : ''}
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div className={`form-group ${password.touched && password.invalid ? 'has-danger' : ''}`}>
            <label>Password</label>
            <div>
            {/* {password.touched && password.error && <div className={s.textError}>{password.error}</div>} */}
              <input type="password" className="form-control" {...password}/>
              <div className="password-help-login">
                {password.touched ? password.error : ''}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
               Login
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
          </div>


        </form>
        <FacebookButton fb={FB} />



        <googleLogin/>
        <a href="#" onclick="this.signOut();">Sign out</a>


      </div>

    )
  }
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'LoginForm',
  fields: ['email','password'],
  validate
},null,{loginUser})(LoginForm)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `FACEBOOKLOGIN` isn't the default export in `../constants/index`. Try this:

```
import { FACEBOOKLOGIN } from "../constants/index";
const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000";
//FACEBOOKLOGIN
export function facebookLogin(props){
  const request = axios.post(`${API_URL}/users`,{
    user: {
      email:props.email,
      password:props.password,
      password_confirmation:props.password
    }
  });
  return{
    type: FACEBOOKLOGIN,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

UPDATE: With your new error message, the new problem has to do with `this` binding.  React stops automatically binding `this` to all component methods a while back and now requires you to do that yourself.  To fix this, change your `FacebookButton` constructor to this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.FB = props.fb;
  this.state = {
    message: ""
  };

  this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
}
```

I also see in the render method for `FacebookButton` that you're calling `this.onClick`.  That's not what you want to do.  Try this:

```
   render() {
     const { fields: { email, password }, handleClick, submitting } = this.props
      return (
         <div>
         <div className=
         "fb-login-button"
         data-max-rows="1"
         data-size="medium"
         data-show-faces="true"
         data-auto-logout-link="true"
         onclick={this.onClick}></div>
            <div>{this.state.message}</div>
         </div>
      );
   }
```

UPDATE 2: Now it's telling you that FB is undefined.  If FB is globally available (if you are getting the sdk through a script tag in your html), why not just use it that way instead of taking it as a prop? Ie. change this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout',
         this.onLogout.bind(this));
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange',
         this.onStatusChange.bind(this));
}
```

Comment: Right, but you did `import FACEBOOKLOGIN from '../constants/index'`. Try putting curly braces around `FACEBOOKLOGIN`

Comment: yes you are right. I've added the braces, and I updated my error messages, can you help me figure out the issue?

Comment: yes, I changed my code as you said, and new errors come, can you help me:)

Comment: @D.Kenny updated again.  If you run into another error, try solving it yourself first.  That last one was **very** simple to fix based on the error message

Comment: I updated my question again, now I still received the error sometimes, and I can only see the facebook login page, other components were disappeared. Can you help me on that?:)

Comment: I'm totally new to react redux... @taylorc93